# mySQL - outputting the sum of two calculated fields

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert rank fields into a total score. So for example I have two fields, rank1 and rank1.

I can convert those to scores using:

```
rank1, 
CASE WHEN rank1=1 THEN 10
            WHEN rank1=2 THEN  6
            WHEN rank1=3 THEN  3
            WHEN rank1=4 THEN  2
            WHEN rank1=5 THEN  1
                        ELSE  0 END  AS score1,
rank2, 
CASE WHEN rank=1 THEN 10
            WHEN rank2=2 THEN  6
            WHEN rank2=3 THEN  3
            WHEN rank2=4 THEN  2
            WHEN rank2=5 THEN  1
                        ELSE  0 END  AS score2,
```

But how can I output the sum of score1 + score2?

I have tried:

```
SUM(score1 + score2) AS TotalScore,
```

But it doesn't like it as score1 and score2 ar not fields in the table.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
rank1, 
CASE WHEN rank1=1 THEN 10
            WHEN rank1=2 THEN  6
            WHEN rank1=3 THEN  3
            WHEN rank1=4 THEN  2
            WHEN rank1=5 THEN  1
                        ELSE  0 END  AS score1,
rank2, 
CASE WHEN rank2=1 THEN 10
            WHEN rank2=2 THEN  6
            WHEN rank2=3 THEN  3
            WHEN rank2=4 THEN  2
            WHEN rank2=5 THEN  1
                        ELSE  0 END  AS score2,
(CASE WHEN rank1=1 THEN 10
            WHEN rank1=2 THEN  6
            WHEN rank1=3 THEN  3
            WHEN rank1=4 THEN  2
            WHEN rank1=5 THEN  1
                        ELSE  0 END
+
CASE WHEN rank2=1 THEN 10
            WHEN rank2=2 THEN  6
            WHEN rank2=3 THEN  3
            WHEN rank2=4 THEN  2
            WHEN rank2=5 THEN  1
                        ELSE  0 END) as TotalScore
```

Comment: I assumed that the sum() OP was attempting to use was a hold over from Excel summing, which is really just addition of two fields and not a like a DB sum/group by

Comment: Basically in the above which shows score1 and score2, I just need to be able to output the value of score1 + score2. The above looks like it should work, but gives a syntax error, with or without SUM before (CASE..

Comment: I missed the END on the first CASE statement. I have added that in the solution and it should work without throwing a Syntax Error now.

Comment: Thanks - That was one thing I didn't try as it made sense that the END was at the end of the calculation. Its displaying results now, but not the right ones. In an example, where rank1 = 2 and rank2 is NULL it should give a TotalScore of 6, but is showing 54. Or if rank1 = 1 and rank it is showing a score of 210 when it should be 10.

Comment: In this example is it giving the SUM from values from more than one row? It should just be the sum of two scores, based on two fields in the same row.

Comment: 56? I could understand it giving null in that first problem, but 56 makes no sense. No, this will not sum multiple rows unless you wrap the addition of the two case statements in a sum, only add individual ranks from distinct rows.

Comment: Not sure what was up - there was no consistency to it - it wasn't giving the same value for different rows where the rank values were the same. Which made me wonder if it was looking up values from multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Put SUM() around the CASE statement:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN rank1=1 THEN 10
        WHEN rank1=2 THEN  6
        WHEN rank1=3 THEN  3
        WHEN rank1=4 THEN  2
        WHEN rank1=5 THEN  1
                    ELSE  0 END)  AS score1,
.....
```

Comment: Do I need a SUM around each CASE statement for the different scores? Or just SUM around the bracketed CASE statements adding up all the scores? The later seemed to make more sense, but that gave me a syntax error.